# ESXi 6.5 install not recognizing datastore from previous version

Tags: vmware-esxi

I installed a fresh ESXi 6.5 and connected my RAID and local storage datastores from my previous 5.1 build. The LSI RAID was recognized and works fine, but the local spinning disk that I was using as additional storage does not appear as a datastore.

It shows under storage devices, but with a few of the following messages

```
1. [missing "en-us.storage.partitionTypes." translation]
```

I've tried re-scanning. I'm assuming it's an ESXi version issue. Is there anyway to get this working?

Comment: you could try https://www.v-front.de/2013/11/how-to-make-your-unsupported-sata-ahci.html?m=1

Comment: The previous version was which version?